# How can I use relative paths in symfony 3

Tags: php, routes, symfony-3.4

Im using realtive paths too link between my twig templates but as soon as I start switching back and forth between 2 urls, things get a little messy. This error only appears if the url is a 3 part component like "http://domainname.com/library/book/harry-potter-1/"

For example if I have two links, lets say "something/editions/1", "something/editions/2" and I start switching between them the URL will start to stack up like this "domain_name/something/editions/1", "domain_name/something/editions/editions/2", "domain_name/something/editions/editions/editions/1", see what I mean.

I have done my research and I know that I can use absolute paths to "solve" my issue but I would rather have this ...

```
<a href="something/editions/1"> Editions 1 </a>
```

over this ...

```
<a href="{{ absolute_path("something/editions/1") }}"> Editions 1 </a>

{# Twig translates it to #} 
<a href="http://domainname.com/something/editions/1"> Editions 1 </a>
```

Is it possible to add some sort of symfony configuration so I can prevent the urls to stack up.

Can I say to symfony something like hey, every time a URL is clicked start from '/'.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in front of me all of the time, relative paths must begin with a '/' in order to work, instead of "something/editions/1" you need to use "/something/editions/1".